# How to get value from text box Using Jquery in asp.net and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am trying to get value from text boxes in my views in asp.net using jquery. i have also used bootstrap in my project. Due to it jquery is not getting value. kindly anyone guide me how to get value in this case.

**javascript:**

```
function Validate()        
{             
        var username = $("#username").attr('value');     
        var password = $("#password").attr('value');      
        var url = "/User/ValidateUser/";            

        alert(username);
        $.ajax({                                // function calling
            url: url,
            data: { userId: username, Password: password },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data)
            {
                if (data == "1")
                {
                    //alert("Valid user Id ");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Invalid user Id ");
                }
            },
            error: function (reponse)
            {
                alert("Invalid user ID");
            }
        });
    }
```

**html:**

```
<input class="textbox" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">

<input class="textbox" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Comment: Where do you call function from and what makes you say it *"is not getting value"*? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: <input type="button" value="Login" class="btn" onclick="Validate()">                         i am calling this function on button click event

Comment: sir its not working ...

Answer (score 0):

attr(key) gets what is in the markup.  Not what the current value is.  You should use val() when trying to get the value of an input.  As demonstrated below.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  console.log(
    $('#test').attr('value'),
    $('#test').val()
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" value="Yo yo man" />
<button>Log Value</button>
```

Comment: This is, of course, assuming the logic is ran after the markup exists in the dom.  If you try to do a selector on elements that do not exist in the dom yet, you will not find them to get their value in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Use .val() to get value from input , textarea elements.
Please refer : 
http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
var username = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
```